# Como relacionar duas tabelas diferentes dentro de uma PROCEDURE? PLSQL

Tags: pl-sql, stored-procedures

Preciso criar uma `procedure` (em PL-SQL) que seja de marcar_Agendamentos, nelas vou incluir informações como data, paciente e também o id_médico responsável e o id_especialidade, o que venho quebrando a cabeça é que gostaria de desenvolver uma condição onde fosse possível verificar se o id_medico inserido e id_especialidade é o que retorna na tabela médicos, onde tem o id,nome e a área em que cada médico atende, evitando que na hora de inserir os dados a pessoa troque e coloque uma outra especialidade para o médico.

Está sendo bem difícil , já procurei soluções sem sucesso e também já tentei as minhas mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Poderia pegar a especialidade através da tabela médico e da relação médico -> especialidade. Assim na tabela agendado basta ter uma fk para médico.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você poderia usar cursores pra trazer as informações que vc quer destas tabelas. Caso o retorno do cursor seja diferente de nulo, por exemplo, você terá as informações que precisa e com a certeza que eles estão nas respectivas tabelas.
Por exemplo:

```
Table medicos:
-id_medico
-id_especialidade
```

Seu cursor seria algo como:

```
cursor get_info_doc (id_doc medicos.id_medico%type, id_esp medicos.id_especialidade) is
 select * from medicos where id_medico = id_doc and id_especialidade = id_esp;
```

Aí na sua verificação seria tipo:

```
if get_info_doc%NOTFOUND then
...
else
...
end if;
```

Talvez dê pra adaptar algo pra vc com isso, espero ter ajudado.